# How can I dynamically open an amp-iframe in AMPhtml?

Tags: amp-html

I'm using an amp-iframe or two on my website quite successfully, as well as some dynamic amp-list components as well.

I've a relatively complex set of HTML which I'd like to make into an amp-iframe, rather than being part of the main page, since it's computationally difficult to compute. An amp-iframe would be ideal for this: but I'd rather not have it load automatically with page load.

Instead, I'd like the amp-iframe to load once someone hits a button. "Show more information" would then open an amp-iframe and load in the difficult stuff.

I'm not sure of the way of doing this.

- I've been using hidden DIVs with setState to change the visible details. Can I set an amp-iframe as invisible, and would it only load if it was turned visible?
- Could I simply use setState to change the SRC of the amp-iframe?
- If this amp-iframe is at the bottom of the page (always below the viewport) would it only be loaded when it was coming into view anyway (i.e. is this actually already achieving what I want of only being loaded if a user wants to see it?)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Well, I don't have a *problem*. I've no error. The only example I could give is a vanilla AMP page with an IFRAME in it, and that's not going to be any assistance to anyone.

What I've learnt so far is that if the amp-iframe is at the bottom of the page, below the viewport, it is still loaded at page-load. An example for that is [on this page](https://podnews.net/podcast/1200361736), where you can see a call to a cloudfront address (the iframe) going through upon page load, even when it is below the viewport. So at least I can answer #3 - "no."